# How can I create a group table in Markdown?

Tags: python, github, markdown, readme

I want to create a table in Markdown like this:

[image: screenshot of a table with joined groups]

or like this:

[image: screenshot of another table with joined groups]

I've found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307289/tableau-like-grouped-table-in-r-for-markdown) but it was for `rmarkdown` so I don't know how to implement this in python markdown or just in a normal markdown file.

Actually, I am creating a GitHub readme file and there I am creating a table mentioning the team members and their contributions and some other similar tasks.

**Note:** This question has nothing to do with the Iris dataset

Comment: You can use pipes to make tables

- https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/
- https://gist.github.com/ww9/44f08d44327a40d2ab309a349bebec57

Answer (score 0):

You can use [box-drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) [in a code block](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks) (```` ``` ````) to do this.

```
              │        Petal       │        Sepal
              │    Length    Width │    Length    Width
──────────────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────
 setosa       │     1.462    0.246 │     1.462    0.246
 versicolor   │     4.260    1.326 │     5.936    2.770
 virginica    │     5.552    2.026 │     6.588    2.974
```